# Source documents are returned even when LLM is returning "I'm sorry, but I don't have access to this information ". when i am doing QnA over documents

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am doing question and answering over some documents, using conversationalretrieval chain with conversationbuffer memory, i am keeping return source_documents to True.
Now when i am asking a question whose information is not present in my documents the LLM is returning "I'm sorry, but I don't have access to personal information like your name" . But it is still returning some source_documents, is there a way so that it doesnt return me any source/source_documents in case in does not know the answer?

i was expecting it shouldnt return me any source documents incase it doesnt know the answer.